# CSS3 Ribbon in HTML table

Tags: css, html-table, ribbon

I refer to the tutorial of [CSS3-Tricks Ribbon tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/ribbon/).

I'd like to adjust the `th` element inside a table with CSS3 so that it looks like the ribbon in the tutorial.

I've set up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qU7Ba/) to test it, but unfortunately I can't do it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving `display: block` to `.ribbon`, and take off the background from the table.
Here's  **[example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/qU7Ba/1/)**.

Or you can try to add to the table: `position:relative` and `z-index:-2`.
Here's **[example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/qU7Ba/2/)**.

***Update 1***
And here is with 100% width:[**example 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/qU7Ba/5/).

***Update 2***
**[example 4](http://jsfiddle.net/qU7Ba/6/)**
**[example 5](http://jsfiddle.net/qU7Ba/7/)**

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Is there a way to make it over the full table (width:100%)? I tried it, but it didn´t work: http://jsfiddle.net/qU7Ba/3/

Comment: sorry, you have misunderstood me. I don´t want to make it over the whole width of table, the ribbon should be appear before and after. So the content area of <th> is 100% and the effect of the ribbon should be not inside the table

Comment: Now I got it! Please see example 4 and 5